# Usage of the word "curt"

Tags: vocabulary

I have googled the meaning of the word "*curt*", and google provided me with this definition "*rudely brief*.". When I searched for its meaning on Dictionary.com it seems that it can also be used to mean "*short; shortened.*". Is the second meaning archaic or can it be used in writing to say, for instance, "*The curt mane of a horse*."?

Comment: I think it's just called *short mane* http://www.horseforum.com/horse-grooming/short-mane-99965/. To be curt, is give a short, sometimes, brusque reply or answer. Don't use it to substitute "short"

Comment: It may have been different in the past, but these days I think *curt* is used almost exclusively to describe manner or language, not more generally.

Comment: “can it be used in writing to say, for instance, "The curt mane of a horse."?” Short answer: No. Slightly longer answer: Physical objects are never *curt*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your Dictionary.com](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/curt)
Care should be taken in the use of "curt".
While it may not always have a negative meaning by the user, a listener or reader might not always understand. Historically "curt" could be interchanged for "short", but "short" has become the much more common word.
[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curt%2C%20short&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccurt%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcurt%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCurt%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCURT%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cshort%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bshort%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BShort%3B%2Cc0).
It would be best not to use "curt" except in familiar contexts.